# Chosen jquery plugin - Get the selected text/ label (not value) of multiple selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I have a [chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) multi-select box as below

No matter how many items are selected, I want to get only the current (single) selected label.
I found that `params.selected` can get the selected value, but what I need is the selected label.

I also cannot use `$("#purposes option:selected").text()` because it get multiple selected labels,

```js
$("#purposes").chosen().on("change", function(event, params) {
  console.log(params.selected); //this works for value only
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>


<select class="chosen-select" id="purposes" multiple data-placeholder="Purposes">
  <option value="1">Massaging</option>
  <option value="2">Downloading</option>
  <option value="3">Research</option>
  <option value="4">Travel arrangements</option>
  <option value="8">Banking</option>
  <option value="9">OTHERS</option>
</select>
```

Comment: what do you mean by `I want to get only the current (single) selected label.` ?

Comment: `$("#purposes option[value='"+params.selected+"'").text()` …?

Comment: I made you a snippet so we can better understand what is going on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could find the option with the selected value and get its label by `.text()`

```
$(this).find(`option[value=${params.selected}]`).text()
```

```js
$("#purposes").chosen().on("change", function(event, params) {
  console.log($(this).find(`option[value=${params.selected}]`).text())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="chosen-select" id="purposes" multiple data-placeholder="Purposes">
  <option value="1">Massaging</option>
  <option value="2">Downloading</option>
  <option value="3">Research</option>
  <option value="4">Travel arrangements</option>
  <option value="8">Banking</option>
  <option value="9">OTHERS</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Or this: `$(\`option[value=${params.selected}]\`,this).text()`

Comment: Anyway, it was actually answered in the comment to the question more than 20 minutes ago - I should have paid more attention to the use of the plugin